# who calls the form load event in windows form program?

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms

who calls all the events like form load or other events in windows forms program or page load event in the asp.net pages or any other events in java programs?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You can set properties in the Load event handler.
    this.Text = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    this.Top = 60;
    this.Left = 60;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET runtime calls events on your windows. Some events are triggered by messages sent to your windows, others are unique for WinForms and triggered by the runtime itself.

See for example [Order of Events in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When a Windows Forms application starts, the startup events of the main form are raised in the following order:
>
> 1. Control.HandleCreated
> 2. Control.BindingContextChanged
> 3. Form.Load
> 4. Control.VisibleChanged
> 5. Form.Activated
> 6. Form.Shown

For ASP.NET, see [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there any name given to that runtime that calls the events ..